# Using an array in a c# constructor arguments

Tags: c#

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class MyHash : IComparable
{
    public byte[] myBytes = new byte[15];

    // constructor
    MyHash(byte[] incomingByteArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            myBytes[i] = incomingByteArray[i];
        }
    }
   // other irrelevant stuff here
 }
```

Now later when I want to use this class, I try:

```
MD5 hashMaker = MD5.Create();
byte[] hash = hashMaker.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(thisSubstring));
listOfHashes.Add(new MyHash(hash));
```

...and Visual Studio (2013) complains that MyHash "does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments".

So speaking as something of a c# novice and probably misusing words to boot, I think the MyHash constructor is getting a single reference to 'hash' and what it is expecting is an array...?

I can hack this up to have a constructor with 15 arguments and instantiate it (new MyHash(hash[0],hash[1], etc.)) but that seems like the wrong thing to do and I fear I will pay for it in the programmer after life.  I could convert the byte[] into an ArrayList or something but that adds quite an overhead when you're running through that loop millions of times.

I also didn't see a way to specify a specific array length in the constructor (e.g., bytes[15]).

So what is the Correct And True way to send an array of bytes (byte[]) to a constructor?

Thanks very much SO!

Comment: Your constructor is private. And you'll have an `IndexOutOfRangeException` on `myBytes[i]` when `i` is 15 (the last iteration of the loop).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
MyHash(byte[] incomingByteArray)
```

to

```
public MyHash(byte[] incomingByteArray)
```

if you don't include an access modifier such as public or protected, it will be private by default.

Comment: Wow - that was a very silly mistake.  Thank you so much.